# "grep -Rl" results as vi arguments with proper space support

Tags: grep, filenames, vi

I am trying to do something like

```
vi `grep -Rl 'keyword'`
```

But I want to support spaces in the file names.

```
vi "`grep -Rl 'keyword'`"
```

Does *not* do what I need, it turns the grep output in a single argument with \n in it.

I tried

```
vi "`grep -Rl 'keyword'`| xargs"
```

And while it looks better, the result still is a single argument (now with spaces instead of \n).

Is there a good way to do this? Bash is fine, bonus points for being POSIX compliant.

PS.

I am aware the -R option is not available for all grep implementations and that bash has the nice nestable "$()" notation for ``` `` ```.

Comment: Why do you need to pipe this after `vi`? Why not just use `grep -Rl "keyword" /path/to/files/*`?

Comment: I am not piping to vi, I am using the output as arguments to vi, hence vi will open all the files listed by grep. (the -l option only ouputs file names). The idea is that the files containing `keyword` should be modified...
*edit*

modified the question title to no longer mention pipe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `find`:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -q 'pattern' {} \; -exec vi {} +
```

This would look into each regular file in or below the current directory for a line that matches `pattern`.  For these found files, `vi` would be started.

If there are several hundreds of these files, `vi` would be called for batches of files.  Change `-exec vi {} +` to `-exec vi {} \;` to call `vi` once for each file.

We use `grep -q` as we're not actually interested in the output of `grep` at all, only its exit status.

This would allow for any valid Unix filename, and is completely POSIX compliant (recursive `grep` is not).

Comment: Great, this works a charm :) Did not realize you could use multiple exec-s on find, nor that the exit code was checked there...

Comment: @Fictional Yes, each `-exec` works as a "test" on the pathname that `find` is looking at, just like `-type` and `-name` etc.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
grep -Rl 'pattern' | xargs -d '\n' vi
```

I don't know how POSIXy the `-d` option is.

If you have GNU tools, this is better to allow any file name:

```
grep -Rlz 'pattern' | xargs -0 vi
```

Comment: The last one does not work for me. The first one is nice though, and is a more general case solution. Which is nice.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, in bash, and assuming that you don't have so many matching filenames that you would exceed `$(getconf ARG_MAX)`, would be to loop over the expansion of `**` under globstar and build up an array of filenames that match:

```
shopt -s globstar
matching_files=()
for entry in **
do
  [ -f "$entry" ] || continue
  grep -q 'pattern' -- "$entry" && matching_files+=("$entry")
done
vi -- "${matching_files[@]}"
```

The loop will find non-hidden files and directories at and underneath the current directory; the first test we do is to see if we have a plain file. If so, we run a quiet/silent `grep` against it for the desired pattern. If the file contains the pattern, we add its filename to the matching_files array. At the end, we run `vi` on the safely-expanded list of entries in the array.

If you also want to search hidden files and directories, set `shopt -s dotglob`.